# SQL query string to get next N records in the table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm building chat application. In the chat screen I want to display last 20 message and if we scroll up, it will load older message. Could anyone bring me SQL query string to load next 10 last records?

This is my SQL string to load last 20 records:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_chat_content
    ORDER BY message_id DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS TEMP
ORDER BY TEMP.message_id ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ID is alwais increasing, your query will return the last 10 records:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
     SELECT *
     FROM tbl_chat_content
     ORDER BY message_id DESC
     LIMIT 10
  ) AS TEMP
ORDER BY
  TEMP.message_id ASC
```

you can specify an [OFFSET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) to get the next 10 records (from 11 to 20):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_chat_content
    ORDER BY message_id DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
  ) AS TEMP
ORDER BY
  TEMP.message_id ASC
```

this from 21 to 30, etc.:

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

or different syntax:

```
LIMIT 20,10
```